# How to create a column that enumarate the month based on it's month number?

Tags: powerbi

So I have the following data table:

| Month | Month## | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| November | 11 | BC221 |
| July | 7 | 1232SAD |
| August | 8 | DSAGD323 |
| December | 12 | OKSDF93 |
| October | 10 | OPAFSD83 |
| September | 9 | POWER928 |
| August | 8 | DSAGD323 |
| December | 12 | DASF32 |
| October | 10 | HSKJFH73264 |
| September | 9 | 9812973HJKSDF |

And I want to create a new columns that enumerate/rank the month in a ascending order like this:

| Month | Month## | id | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| November | 11 | BC221 | 5 |
| July | 7 | 1232SAD | 1 |
| August | 8 | DSAGD323 | 2 |
| December | 12 | OKSDF93 | 6 |
| October | 10 | OPAFSD83 | 4 |
| September | 9 | POWER928 | 3 |
| August | 8 | DSAGD323 | 2 |
| December | 12 | DASF32 | 6 |
| October | 10 | HSKJFH73264 | 4 |
| September | 9 | 9812973HJKSDF | 3 |

So as you can see above July is going to be the first, August the second, September the third and so on. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way;
simply; Subtract 6 from the month number, if the result is greater than 0, leave it; otherwise, add 6 to the original value;

[image]